# Clip all layers of a GeoPackage (GPKG) in one step

Tags: qgis, sql, clip, geopackage

I would like to clip all layers of a GPKG-File to a given extend (canvas, mask layer, rectangle...) in one step. I could use clipping in batch mode but isn't there a nicer solution doing this in one step (SQL, QGIS)?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done without using python

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?  I find the QGIS 3.8 batch mode to be very fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -spat parameter in ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#ogr2ogr affects all available layers. This selects data withing the given rectangle from all layers if you write only the name of the datasource into the command but not the layername. So just "...input.gpkg" instead of "...input.gpkg selected_layer".

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -spat 100000 6000000 101000 6001000 subset.gpkg input.gpkg
```

Various clip options should work as well for all the layers. The -sql option would require writing names of all the tables explicitly into the SQL statement (FROM and also into WHERE) and that would not be nice.

Comment: Thanks for this. `ogr2ogr` is great!  Here's a modified version for extracting a single country worth of data from the Natural Earth geopackage.

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -spat -25 62 -10 67 -clipsrc spat_extent \
 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
 "ne_iceland.gpkg" natural_earth_vector.gpkg
```